# Why javascript does not complain when the parameters count in function call is not matching with that of function declaration?

Tags: javascript, function

In javascript, I declared a function as follows:

```
function foo(a)
{
    console.log(a);
}
```

Here, the function declaration contains only one parameter. But when I used function calls with more than one parameter, like

```
foo(a,b,c)
```

javascript did not complain about the extra parameters. Why? What happens to the extra parameters?

Comment: just have a look here: [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: Because function calls in JS are [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because that's how the language designers decided to implement it. It does allow for all kinds of functionality, roughly equivalent to optional parameters.

> What happens to the extra parameters?

They're available on the `arguments` object from within the method:

```js
function foo(a)
{
    console.log(a);
    console.log(arguments);
}

foo(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Why is Javascript so forgiving?  Wouldn't the code be more readable if the number of arguments in the call were forced to match the number defined in the declaration?